# Nvidia gtx 970 dual monitors xrandr missing resolution

Tags: drivers, xorg, multiple-monitors, resolution, nvidia-settings

Hello i have a problem after update Nvidia GTX 970 drivers.

Konfiguracja komptutera:
Ram 16GB    Type: DDR3
intel i7 4430 K
SSD 2x GoodRam w RAID 0 madadm
Nvidia GeForce GTX 970
Display Devices:
DFP-4 (DFP-4), Samsung S22B300 (DFP-0)
Notworking well DFP-4 Unknow display (this is Philips 220WS)

Before error it all was great Kernel 3.13.0.-39 and NVIDIA Driver Version: 343.36
Driver change NVIDIA Driver Version: 346.47 
And from now on, no mather what I do my xrandr don't see my second monitor i get only this and can't set up right resolution.

I have try to downgrade driver (purge nvidia before) i have made my X11/xorg.conf by hand with manual and internet

The nvidia-settings don't see other resolution then 800x600 with bad hz like 63+

```
xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2720 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0  
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x800       59.8  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     72.2     60.3     56.2  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        59.9  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     59.9  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 connected 800x600+1920+480 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   800x600        60.3*+
Unknown-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

My xorg.conf

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 346.47  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-01)  Thu Feb 19 19:18:25 PST 2015

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung S22B300"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection
Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Philips"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 60.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 970"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-1: 1920x1080 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24

    EndSubSection
EndSection
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-4"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-D-0: 1600x900_60 +1920+0 {viewportin=1600x900}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24

    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

After reboot it allways back to 800x600 no mather what.

Plz help can't turn this back.
Now i'm on driver 346.47

Comment: any one ? Can any one point solution..